# Can you finish a job without starting it?

Tags: firefly

Let's say I have a job card that says:
Start job: Load 2 contraband on planet X; 
Finish job: Deliver 2 contraband to planet Y"

I have obtained contraband via some other means.
Is it possible to fly straight to planet Y and take a "Work" action that consists of just finishing the job and delivering the contraband?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the job has pickup & drop off locations, you need to visit the two locations in the correct order to finish the job. If the job only has a target location, then you only need to go to one location for completion.

From [the official FAQ](https://www.flamesofwar.com/Portals/0/all_images/GF9/Firefly/Rulebooks/FAQ/Firefly_FAQ_v4.1.pdf) on page 5:

> **Question:** I don’t get doing Jobs: how do I do them?
>
> ..... Each Job will have either a Target or Pick-up
>   Location on the card. You then need to use a
>   Move Action to get your Firefly to the correct
>   location ..... Once you’re at that
>   Location, use a Work Action to progress the Job.
>
> ..... If the Job also has a Drop-Off Location,
>   you’ll need to Fly again to the Drop-Off Location
>   to deliver the Goods before completing the Job. If
>   the Job only has a Target Location, you’re done.

Note the use of the word "need" - it never says that the pickup location is optional.

Think of it this way - if you told someone you'll give them $10 to pick you up a burger from your favourite burger joint, and they give you a burger they already had in their car from somewhere else, they haven't really done the job you were paying them to do.